# Can't copy multiple large files simultaneously in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to copy 200 very large files simulataneously into a specific folder in my website but the copy() function in PHP only allows one large file to be copied at a time. I'm not getting any errors in the error log and I'm able to copy multiple small files simultaneously without any issues. Any solution?

Code:

```
<?php


$path_to_large_file_1 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_1 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file1.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_1, $newfile_1);



$path_to_large_file_2 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_2 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file2.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_2, $newfile_2);


$path_to_large_file_3 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_3 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file3.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_3, $newfile_3);



$path_to_large_file_4 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_4 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file4.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_4, $newfile_4);




$path_to_large_file_5 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_5 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file5.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_5, $newfile_5);




?>
```

Comment: What do you mean Simultaneously? even the `cp` program in linux does it one at a time.  to copy 200 files at once you would probably overload your memory and cpu power

Comment: @Forbs if you look at the OP's previous question you can see what he thinks is simultaneous (which its not of course) but its still unclear what the actual issue is here

Comment: Probably a Timeout because he's using PHP

Comment: That's not PHP's fault. He is probably using the inbuilt PHP function to copy files in a loop. To copy simultaneously he probably needs to use something like rsync or Pthreads.

Comment: I've tried writing two scripts that write to 2 different files, the first script stops copying as soon as the second begins. No errors in the error log so it can't be due to a timeout.

Comment: I am getting same problem but in my case the file are <1mb. And when i add `sleep(1);` after `copy` func, it works fine..
So, is it a bug of php??

Answer (score 0):

Probably a timeout, since copying may take several minutes.

To increase execution time edit your php.ini:

max_execution_time = 3600

Use a very high value, like 3600 seconds (1 hour).

For further information check:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried writing two scripts that write to 2 different files, the first script stops copying as soon as the second begins. No errors in the error log

Comment: Can you publish a simplified example script, please? What OS, PHP version and file sizes are you using? I will try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question and added the code. I'm using php 5.6 on CentOS 7. The file size is unknown since the files are live streams. My objective is to download all the files concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

To do work simultaneously you could use the [Thread class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php).

example for your code

```
<?php

class FileCopy extends Thread {

    private $src = null;
    private $dest = null;

    public function __construct($src, $dest) {
        $this->src = $src;
        $this->dest = $dest;
    }

    public function run() {
        if ($this->src != null && $this->dest != null)
            copy($this->src, $this->dest);
    }
};

$threads = array();
$files = array(
     array("url" => "http://very_large_file1.zip", "path" => "/home/username/public_html/files/file1.zip"),
     array("url" => "http://very_large_file2.zip", "path" => "/home/username/public_html/files/file2.zip"),
     array("url" => "http://very_large_file3.zip", "path" => "/home/username/public_html/files/file3.zip"),
     array("url" => "http://very_large_file4.zip", "path" => "/home/username/public_html/files/file4.zip")
);

foreach($files AS $file) {
    $thread = new FileDownload($file["url"], $file["path"]);
    $thread->start();
    $threads[] = $thread;
}

foreach($threads AS $thread) $thread->join();

echo "The downloads are finished.";
```

**EDIT 1:**

NB: You need the php extension `pthreads` to be installed ([*installation guides*](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php)).

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in /home/username/public_html/test.php on line 3'